# Simplifying wrapper creation

Tags: c++

Sometimes I find myself writing really simple wrappers, where a wrappers method directly corresponds to one method of the adapted class, i.e.:

```
class ToBeAdapted
{
    public:
    void a();
    void b(int arg);
};

class Wrapper
{
   public:
   void newA()
   {
      _adapted.a();
   }

   void newB(int arg)
   {
      _adapted.b(arg);
   }

   private:
   ToBeAdapted _adapted;
};
```

Can this (perhaps with the use of template magic and/or dark preprocessor rituals?) be generalized somewhat, simply to save writing time and make it easier to switch the wrapper interface later?

Something like this would be cool:

```
wrap_around<ToBeAdapted>(ToBeAdapted::a, newA, ToBeAdapted::b,newB) Wrapper; //Creates the same wrapper class as specified above.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using private inheritance:

```
class Wrapper : ToBeAdapted
{
  public:
    void newA() { a(); }
    void newB(int arg) { b(arg); }
};
```